# Blender 2.78 release doesn't start in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: installation, linux, versions

I usually use the PPA: thomas-schiex/blender for installing Blender. I had never problems before with it. In September 2016 I used Blender 2.78 RC, and it worked well. But in October I've installed Blender 2.78 release (using apt-get install command), and my Blender is not starting now. What to do? Thanks!

Comment: well, without any proper error messages, I don't think you won't get any answer on that. Besides... If it already ran under your system and you did not do any major changes to it (like a new gfx driver, upgrading ubuntu to a new major release...) it's most likely a problem with the build you get from the repo.

Comment: @metaphor_set- big thanks for answer! I don't receive any error message. Just see the launcher in the pannel (KDE in KX Studio 14.04 (it's based on Ubuntu14.04)), after about 30 sec., the launcher disappears and that's all. May be there's some way to display in linux what is going on? Could you or somebody give advice?

Comment: P.C.: I returned the state of system to where the Blender 2.78 RC had a place. I used Systemback program -  Blender launches good. After installing Blender 2.78 release - it doesn't start again.
 Also, I tried to delete Blender program using 'sudo apt-get remove blender' - command. After installing Blender 2.78 release - it doesn't start.

Comment: Try the tarball from https://www.blender.org/download/ . Extract it somewhere in your home directory and see it it starts. If it does, then it's most likely the build you have from the repo, that causes the failure.

Comment: Did you copy over the settings from your previous Blender version? If so (just an idea), maybe try removing Blender's settings folder? I imagine it's possible some settings or add-on data intended for an older version is causing a conflict.

Comment: @metaphor_set: I downloaded the tarbal and lounched file 'blender.desctop' - it's not starting Blender. BUT if I launch 'blender' file - it works well. May be the problem has relations with launching icons? 

I've made some screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wLXUcKN8LAekNqcnpub1VSMjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Mentalist: Thanks for answer! After removing through 'sudo apt-get remove', I deleted folder "/home/cooltehno/.config/blender" - is it right? But this hasn't  resolved the problem :(

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure about the exact steps on Ubuntu, I only know how to do it on OS X. And I don't know if doing this would resolve the problem - I guess it's also possible that the origin of the problem is within the settings of the OS. If you really suspect that the problem is caused by a difference in Blender's code between the RC version you used successfully and the official release, maybe you should submit a bug report.

Comment: May be this will help to understand something:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wLXUcKN8LAQkk2STk1M01XZkk/view?usp=sharing

I've run in console 'Roor>usr>lib>blender' - file. This has given me massage:
/usr/lib/blender/blender: error while loading shared libraries: libosdGPU.so.3.0.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: The additional question. Does anybody know other PPA(s) for stable Blender 2.78 release? (I mean instead of 'thomas-schiex/blender')

Comment: Try downloading directly from blender.org. No need to use PPA

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use apt-get at all! Just download the zip from blender.org, extract it somewhere, then run the blender executable you will find inside the folder. That's what I did and it worked from the first time!

Answer (score 0):

I've made the next attempt 'sudo apt-get upgrade' of my system today. Blender 2.78 was upgraded successfully and now it's starting well. I suppose the problem was really as @metaphor_set told - "the repo, that causes the failure". I think they finally fixed the build.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I had to upgrade the Open SubDiv (OSD) library in Synaptic (Linux Ubuntu) to 3.1.1

This is how the line looked in Synaptic:

[image]